# How can I identify if a device listed in MediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is virtual?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

For legal requirements in some streaming services it is mandatory that the video and audio captured come from real physical devices on the user device.
The [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo) does not identify virtual devices.
Is there any way to identify if a device listed by MediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is virtual?

Thanks